# You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'lstm_2_input' exception

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am building a GAN system with LSTM as discriminator and classifier.
The other question with the same error did not help me.
The error is:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'sequential_2_input' with dtype float and shape [1,30,2]
>        [[Node: sequential_2_input = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[1,30,2], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

I am trying to rearrange [this](https://github.com/wouterbulten/deeplearning-resources/blob/master/notebooks/1%20-%20Getting%20started%20with%20Generative%20Adversarial%20Networks%20using%20Keras%20and%20MNIST.ipynb) example but I am not able to make it work. The exception arises when I try to generate the fake examples feeding noise to the generator.

This is my code:

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, np, TimeDistributed
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop, Adam


def discriminator():
    net = Sequential()
    input_shape = (1, 30, 2)

    net.add(LSTM(10, stateful=True, batch_input_shape=input_shape))

    net.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

    return net


def generator():
    net = Sequential()

    input_shape = (1, 30, 2)

    net.add(LSTM(10, return_sequences=True, stateful=True, batch_input_shape=input_shape))

    net.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(2, activation='linear')))

    return net


net_discriminator = discriminator()
# net_discriminator.summary()
net_generator = generator()
# net_generator.summary()

optim_discriminator = RMSprop(lr=0.0008, clipvalue=1.0, decay=1e-10)
model_discriminator = Sequential()
model_discriminator.add(net_discriminator)
model_discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optim_discriminator, metrics=['accuracy'])

model_discriminator.summary()


optim_adversarial = Adam(lr=0.0004, clipvalue=1.0, decay=1e-10)
model_adversarial = Sequential()
model_adversarial.add(net_generator)

# Disable layers in discriminator
for layer in net_discriminator.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model_adversarial.add(net_discriminator)
model_adversarial.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optim_adversarial, metrics=['accuracy'])

model_adversarial.summary()


noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (1, 30, 2))

fake_data = net_generator.predict(noise)
```

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the error? It seems it's not in the fake_data line.

Comment: The error is generated when the fake_data line is executed:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "[...]/test.py", line 58, in <module> gen_tra = net_generator.predict(noise) [....]`

Comment: Can you print the summary of `net_generator` **immediately before** this line?

Comment: `_______________________`
`Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #  ` 
`======================`
`lstm_2 (LSTM)                (1, 30, 10)               520 `      
`________________________`
`time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (1, 30, 2)                22        `
`======================`
`Total params: 542
Trainable params: 542
Non-trainable params:0`